# How to make my python project deployable?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, deployment, setuptools

In my free time I am developing a small python project based on django. I use several other python packages to improve user and my development experience.

I have understand, that I run `pip install pkgname` to install a module named `pkgname` and then I use `from pkgname import somewhat` and go one and everything is fine and fluffy. I understand why to use virtualenv and already use serious tools like coverage and travis-ci.

Now, I want to the next step. At the moment, my project is not ready for world wide deployment. But I like to prepare for this as soon as possible. [It's called Palco and hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/omeinusch/Palco).

Usually, I think, `pip` is the current default to install python modules. But the application I develop **is nothing developers will use in their project** but users will. So, nobody will do `pip install palco` and then write `from palco import hellyeah`. **But they will configure their favourite web server to run django's wsgi-handler.**

Currently, I would tell people,

> please download this archive.zip, extract it and configure your webserver as mentioned

But this is a very php-way of deployment (just throw your files in a directory).

**How make I my end-user python project deployable? Do I need a setup.py? Do I miss something?**

I know, trac is installed with pip and then I "deploy" my very on trac-instance with `trac-admin.py`. Should I have a `palco-admin.py` with the same magic effect as trac-admin?

Comment: Have you looked at how similar projects solve the problem ?

Comment: I know only trac as mentioned.

Comment: trac is not a Django project, but anyway: one possible solution would be to install your code with pip and provide a custom command that would create a new django project instance with sensible default settings and urls. Note that you don't need to have your project's apps installed in the django project itself.

Comment: My project is not a extensions of Django but uses it. Django is requirement but I do not add any functionality to Django other people may use except they run my software.

Comment: Django is framework not an app, so there's no "extension", only apps, so whether these apps are meant to be used as "add-ons" (what you call "extensions") or as full-blown "stand-alone" apps is not that relevant. Since "users" of your app will still have to 1/ install your apps one way or another, 2/ write their own settings file(s), possibly 3/ customize the templates and eventually 4/ add some other apps to their project, treating it as any other app and adding a simple command to bootstrap a project using your app(s) and default settings makes sense to me.

Comment: This is not what I want. My problem is your step 1. Except for step 2 people will not customize the existing templates nor add other apps to the project. My question is your step 1: "one way or another". What way is used for python standalone applications?

Comment: Why wouldn't people want to customize the templates or add other apps to their project ??? But anyway: the standard way to distribute stand alone python apps is to package them properly so they can be installed using pip or some similar tool. And since your application is actually a django based web application which does require quite a few other installation steps (configuration, front web server, database, medias directory etc) the best way is still to install it in site-packages and provide a command that will boostrap a django project. I don't get what bother you with this solution ?

Comment: I do not understand your answer. I do not understand what you mean with bootstrapping a django project. Could you please post an answer with an explanation and a example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59944/discussion-between-bruno-desthuilliers-and-omeinusch).